# Put checkedlistbox items in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Adding the items in a `checkedListBox`:

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\\templates");

FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.xml");

foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
      checkedListBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
}

foreach (string i in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
      string[] array1 = i;
      for (int k = 0; k < array1.Length; k++)
      {
              XmlDocument xdoc1 = new XmlDocument();
              xdoc1.Load(array1[k]);
              string s1 = array1[k].ToUpper();
              int n = s1.IndexOf(array1[k]);
              name1 = array1[k].Substring(n);
      }
```

When I'm putting it in an array, with (`string[] array1 = i;`)
it's an giving error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]' "

any suggestions?

Comment: Might want to add the declaration of i.

Comment: @HenrikJepsen: It's the loop variable of the enclosing loop...

Comment: Why are you trying to do `array1=i` what do you want to do with EACH element of the CheckItems?

Comment: Yes, it has just been added to the original question.

Comment: @HenrikJepsen: It was there the whole time... just the code wasn't presented correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that. You will need to do something like this

```
 string[] array1 = new string[] { i };
```

You are trying to assign `string` to `string[]`. Which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] array1 = new string[]{i};

DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\\templates"); 
FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.xml"); 
Array.ForEach(Files, str => checkedListBox1.Items.Add(str.Name)); 
foreach (string i in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems) 
{  
    XmlDocument xdoc1 = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc1.Load(i);
    name1 = i.Substring(i.ToUpper().IndexOf(i));
}
```

Comment: Hey that's now fair. i gave the same answer before him.

Comment: Hey that's now fair. i gave same answer b4. & u r using more code lines  that required.

DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\\templates");

            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.xml");

            Array.ForEach(Files, str => checkedListBox1.Items.Add(str.Name));            

            foreach (string i in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                XmlDocument xdoc1 = new XmlDocument();
                xdoc1.Load(i);
                string s1 = i.ToUpper();
                int n = s1.IndexOf(i);
                name1 = i.Substring(n);
            }